# When I run Jmeter test using Junit-selenium for three users, login data is entered thrice in a single browser

Tags: jmeter

Three browser windows are launched but all Login details are entered in single browser window. In the other two browser windows login data are not entered and the test gets failed.

It occurs for thread count greater than one.

**Following are the Debugging approaches**

1. Extracted Jar file works well with Jmeter if the thread count is 1.
2. Code works fine when launched from IDE

**IDE Used:** Eclipse

**Project Build:** Using Maven Plugin

**My Test Class (Main Class)**

```
package test.myproject.com;


import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

import com.myproject.baseclass.TestBase;
import com.myproject.elements.HomePage;
import com.myproject.elements.OrganisationPage;
import com.myproject.elements.SideMenu;
import com.myproject.util.Helper;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestLoginPage extends TestBase {
    HomePage homepage;
    SideMenu sidemenu;
    OrganisationPage organisationpage;

    public TestLoginPage(){
        super();
    }   

    @Before
    public void BrowserSetup() {
        intialization();    
    }



    //@Test
    public void MakeLogin() throws InterruptedException {   
        homepage=new HomePage();
        System.out.println(homepage.GetBuildVersion());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        homepage.EnterEmail("apikt@mailinator.com");
        homepage.EnterPassword("*****");
        homepage.PerformLogin();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

    @Test
    public void CreateProject() throws InterruptedException {

        MakeLogin();
        sidemenu=new SideMenu();
        sidemenu.administartion_click();
        sidemenu.organisation_click();
        organisationpage=new OrganisationPage();
        organisationpage.org_setting_click();
        sidemenu.org_user_click();
        organisationpage.create_button_click();
        organisationpage.enter_fullname("loadautomationtest"+Helper.generate_string());
        organisationpage.enter_username("loadautomationtest"+Helper.generate_string());
        organisationpage.enter_emailid("loadautomationtest"+Helper.generate_string()+"@gmail.com");
        organisationpage.click_create();
    }


    @After
    public void TearDown() {
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        //junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
        //Result result = junit.run(TestLoginPage.class);  
        JUnitCore.main("test.myproject.com.TestLoginPage");
    }
}
```

Class will be declared in **Testbase.java** class

```
package com.myproject.baseclass;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestBase {
    public Properties prop;
    public FileInputStream file;
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;


    public TestBase() {
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            file = new FileInputStream("Z:/myproject/assets/property/myproject.properties");
            prop.load(file);
            //data=new ArrayList<String>();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void intialization() {
        if (prop.getProperty("browser").contentEquals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",new File("Z:/myproject/assets/driver/chromedriver.exe").getAbsolutePath());
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No browser found");
        }

        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Alert Site seems very slow!!!! Please increase the page load time out in util class");
            driver.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario/ i don't think this is possible , most documents says that the selelnium scripts execute in only one browser at a time

Comment: @PDHide but when i run selenium in Jmeter using Webdriver sampler plugin it works fine only if i run from Junit issue occurs

Comment: Can you put the code

Comment: @PDHide code will not work as the application hosted in our local server i will make a sample script of any other website and send you the code

Comment: I meant the code showing how you call jmeter from junit

Comment: @PDHide I have created Junit jar file from eclipse using "Junit Request" sampler test has been executed in Jmeter . Whether You need that Junit code if yes i have updated it in my question

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter/ have you tried this . It says there is a checkbox for creating new instance per thread

Comment: @PDHide I have tried but doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing your `intialization();` function, most probably you're facing some form of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

As per [WebDriver FAQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe):

> **Q: Is WebDriver thread-safe?**
>
> A: WebDriver is not thread-safe. Having said that, if you can serialise access to the underlying driver instance, you can share a reference in more than one thread. This is not advisable. You /can/ on the other hand instantiate one WebDriver instance for each thread.

Most probably in your case 3 threads are trying to work with a single WebDriver instance (for example you declared it as [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java))

If you are not feeling too comfortable with multi-threading in Java I would recommend considering switching to [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) or at least [check its source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver) to learn how to properly initialize WebDriver instances so they would be independent and thread-safe

Comment: I have updated my answer with my base class source code(class which has initialization method)

Comment: I was telepathic enough to guess that your WebDriver declaration is `static`, you cannot use static fields safely when it comes to multithreading.

Comment: thank you the issue is because of the static declaration Now its working for me